# Show link on specific time and date?

Tags: coldfusion

I want to show a link at a specific time and date.
Is it possible to get a value from a table and show that link like this

```
<a href="file.cfm?month=#gettopdates.month#&year=#gettopdates.year#">#MonthAsString(month)#  #year#</a>
```

on a specific time and date?

From the table I'm getting the record from a form I submit and there it create 1 record (which will
be enter once a month) I use this table to output the winners which I want to show in the link above
but I only want to show that link at a specific time and date. Not sure if the best way to do this
is in the form I submit. I have a column which the user submit the time and date they want the link to show 
and that goes into the table. Maybe I don't need to insert it into the table , Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Put a CFIF around the link that checks the current time against the time you want the link to show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting it into a table is a good solution then you just need to use a cfif. Note that `now()` would need to represent the exact time and if you're going to match between certain times you would need to update your if as well.

```
<cfif now() GT qryName.myDate>
  <a href="file.cfm?month=#gettopdates.month#&year=#gettopdates.year#">#MonthAsString(month)#  #year#</a>
</cfif>
```